# Cannot download large files from Salesforce URL using C#

Tags: rest-api, httprequest, c#

I'm new to Salesforce. I am trying to download a large file (around `13 MB`) from Salesforce which needs to be uploaded to Azure Storage using `C#`. Below is the URL sample:

`https://mysampleinstance.my.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0693h00000AUzfpAAD`

I've already generated an access token which I tried to call as shown below:

```
 // file.ContentFileLink is the URL above
 var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(file.ContentFileLink);
 req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + sfAccessToken);
 req.Method = "GET";

 WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
       resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);     // upload file to Azure
 }
```

Upon testing, there was no error thrown, however when I checked in Azure Storage, the file size was 0 bytes. Am I missing something with my call above?

Any advice you can give will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is when you try to fetch image data from `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/{ContentDocumentId}` resource, you receive the next response, and only after that a  browser redirects you for image download:

```js
<script>
    var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
    if(window.location.search && window.location.search.length > 1){
        url += window.location.search; // #189617
    }
    var loc = 'https://mysampleinstance.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL='+encodeURIComponent(url);
    window.location = loc;
</script>
```

To download

1. `ContentDocument` files you can access `VersionData` field from specific related [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) record:
   `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{Id}/VersionData`
2. `Document` files you can access [`sObject Blob Retrieve`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) rest resource:
   `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Document/{Id}/body`
3. `Attachment` files you can access [`sObject Blob Retrieve`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) rest resource:
   `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Attachment/{Id}/body`

**C# Example (tested with an image of 50Mb)**

**Client**

```c#
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    const string sfDomain = "mysampleinstance.my.salesforce.com";
    const string connectionString = "Connection String of your Azure Storage Account";
    var token = GetSfAccessToken(sfDomain);
    const string contentVersionId = "0681t00000kVrGeAAK";
    var fileData = DownloadVersionData(sfDomain, token, contentVersionId);
    /*await*/ UploadFile(connectionString, fileData, "filename.jpg");
}
```

**Main Logic**

```c#
struct SfTokenResponse {
    public string? access_token { get; set; }
    public string? instance_url { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public string? token_type { get; set; }
    public string? issued_at { get; set; }
    public string? signature { get; set; }
}

public static string GetSfAccessToken(string domain) {
    var getTokenUrl = $"https://{domain}/services/oauth2/token";
    const string clientId = "clientId";
    const string clientSecret = "clientSecret";
    const string username = "username";
    const string password = "password";

    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest(getTokenUrl, Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
    request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
    request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
    request.AddParameter("username", username);
    request.AddParameter("password", password);

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var body = (SfTokenResponse) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, typeof(SfTokenResponse))!;
    return body.access_token ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

```c#
public static byte[] DownloadVersionData(
        string domain,
        string sfAccessToken,
        string contentVersionId
) {
    var downloadUrl = $"https://{domain}/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{contentVersionId}/VersionData";
    var request = new RestRequest(downloadUrl, Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {sfAccessToken}");
    var client = new RestClient();
    var data = client.DownloadData(request);
    return data;
}
```

```c#
public static async Task UploadFile(
        string connectionString,
        byte[] data,
        string fileName
) {
    // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    // Create a unique name for the container (lowercase only!)
    var containerName = $"sffiles{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    // Create the container and return a container client object
    var containerClient = await serviceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName);
    // Get a reference to a blob
    var blobClient = containerClient.Value.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    // Upload File into a blob container
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(new MemoryStream(data));
}
```

[Documenation [Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage client library v12 for .NET]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)

Comment: This solved my issue perfectly. Thank you so much for the clear explanation and sample code, Oleh! I learned something new today as well :)

Comment: @DeeJ. Glad to know that. You're welcome.)